# rspec assigns(has_many association) not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm a noob to testing in rails and did not follow TDD so I'm testing after the fact. I know my code works when I sanity check it, but I can not get this simple test to work and I have no idea why. I'm trying to learn more about testing so I can become a better rails developer and could use your help.

I'm using the "show" action of the "companies" controller as a dashboard. One thing I do is display all their payments on the dashboard (which is shown in the controller code). I'm simply trying to test that @payments is assigned properly when you get the show action.

This is the failure message I keep getting:

```
  1) CompaniesController GET show reacts to authenticated users sets @payments                                                                                                                                                                                              
 Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:payments)).to match_array([payment1, payment2])                                                                                                                                                                                         
   expected a collection that can be converted to an array with `#to_ary` or `#to_a`, but got nil                                                                                                                                                                       
 # ./spec/controllers/companies_controller_spec.rb:20:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Test:
(The "sets @payments" test is the only one that's failing)

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe CompaniesController do 

describe "GET show" do

    context "reacts to authenticated users" do
        log_in_user

        it "sets @company" do
            company = Fabricate(:company)
            get :show, id: company.id
            expect(assigns(:company)).to eq(company)
        end

        it "sets @payments" do
            company = Fabricate(:company) 
            payment1, payment2 = Fabricate(:payment, company: company), Fabricate(:payment, company: company)
            get :show, id: company.id
            expect(assigns(:payments)).to match_array([payment1, payment2])
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Controller:

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, if: :user_signed_in?
  before_filter :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :destroy]

  def show
    @user = current_user
    @company = @user.company
    @payments = @company.payments.order(id: :desc).page params[:page]
    @payments_count = @company.payments.all
    @refunds_count = @company.refunds.all
    @refunded_amount = @refunds_count.sum(:amount)
    @revenue = @company.payments.all.sum(:amount) - @refunded_amount
    @refund = Refund.new
  end
end
```

Comment: In `@payments = @company.payments.order(id: :desc).page params[:page]`, what is `params[:page]` doing?  I am surprised that doesn't throw a syntax error.

Comment: it's using the kaminari gem for pagination. I got rid of the order and the page part to see if that's what was causing problems so it was: "@payments = @company.payments" only...but that test still failed with the same message.

Comment: I learn something new every day... You could add a quick test for payment1 and payment2 to see if they are getting created as expected.  FWIW I am not a big fan of controller tests... I think most of the focus should be on validating your models and building features tests using a tool like Capybara to verify real user flows through the application.

Answer (score 0):

`@payments` is from the company of the user you signed in, so you also need to make sure `log_in_user` associates `current_user` to the company you want to get `@payments` from.

Comment: When I do that I get the following error:

       Failure/Error: log_in_user                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
       `log_in_user` is not available from within an example (e.g. an `it`   block) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc). It is only available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block).

I am using Devise for authentication

Comment: alright, if that is the case then you probably just need to make sure that current_user.company is exactly the company you created in the spec. I don't see you doing it anywhere yet by looking at the code (Since you are using Fabrication, you probably need to either specify it in your `Fabricator` config, or you can do `compay.update(user_id: 'something')` to achieve that).